# Handling Response Data PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I have created this website which when visited automatically votes on a poll. http://qthostoi.atspace.cc/sdd.php

the problem is that when it submits that it downloads `index.php` I don't want that , How can i prevent that?

Source Code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="http://recipes.wikia.com/index.php" method="POST" onsubmit="alert(2)">
      <input type="hidden" name="title" value="User&#95;blog&#58;Kate&#46;moon&#47;Battle&#95;of&#95;the&#95;Fantasy&#95;Foods&#45;&#95;Round&#95;SIX" />
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ajax" />
      <input type="hidden" name="rs" value="axAjaxPollSubmit" />
      <input type="hidden" name="wpPollId" value="B5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB" />
      <input type="hidden" name="wpVote" value="Vote&#33;" />
      <input type="hidden" name="wpPollRadioB5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB" value="3" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
    </form>
    <script>
      document.forms[0].submit();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried these:

**1:**

```
<?php

    $url = 'http://recipes.wikia.com/index.php';
    $fields = array(
    'title' => "User&#95;blog&#58;Kate&#46;moon&#47;Battle&#95;of&#95;the&#95;Fantasy&#95;Foods&#45;&#95;Round&#95;SIX",
        'action' => "ajax",
        'rs' => "axAjaxPollSubmit",
        'wpPollId' => "B5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB",
        'wpVote' => "Vote&#33;",
        'wpPollRadioB5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB' => "3",
    );
    $count = count($fields);
    $fields = http_build_query($fields);
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, $count);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
?>
```

This do receives Response and prevents download but it don't submits my data to the other domain. I think it submitting wrong data.

**2:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
     $("#contactForm").submit(function(event) 
     {
         /* stop form from submitting normally */
         event.preventDefault();

         /* get some values from elements on the page: */
         var $form = $( this ),
             $submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' ),
             title_value = $form.find( 'input[name="title"]' ).val(),
             action_value = $form.find( 'input[name="action"]' ).val(),
             rs_value = $form.find( 'input[name="wpPollId"]' ).val(),
             wpPollId_value = $form.find( 'input[name="title"]' ).val(),
             wpVote_value = $form.find( 'input[name="wpVote"]' ).val(),
             wpPollRadioB5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB_value = $form.find( 'input[name="wpPollRadioB5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB"]' ).val(),
             message_value = $form.find( 'textarea[name="message"]' ).val(),
             url = $form.attr('action');

         /* Send the data using post */
         var posting = $.post( url, { 
                           title: title_value, 
                           action: action_value, 
                           rs: rs_value, 
                           wpPollId: wpPollId_value,
                           wpVote: wpVote_value,
                           wpPollRadioB5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB: wpPollRadioB5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB_value
                       });

         posting.done(function( data )
         {
             /* Put the results in a div */
             $( "#contactResponse" ).html(data);

             /* Change the button text. */
             $submit.text('Sent, Thank you');

             /* Disable the button. */
             $submit.attr("disabled", true);
         });
    });
</script>

<form id="contactForm" action="http://recipes.wikia.com/index.php" Method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="title" value="User&#95;blog&#58;Kate&#46;moon&#47;Battle&#95;of&#95;the&#95;Fantasy&#95;Foods&#45;&#95;Round&#95;SIX" />
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ajax" />
      <input type="hidden" name="rs" value="axAjaxPollSubmit" />
      <input type="hidden" name="wpPollId" value="B5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB" />
      <input type="hidden" name="wpVote" value="Vote&#33;" />
      <input type="hidden" name="wpPollRadioB5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB" value="3" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
</form>
<div id="contactResponse"></div>



        </body>
</html>
```

It did submitted my data but it downloaded `index.php`

Any Help?

Comment: Is there a reference to something like an api of the page? (Recipes.wikia.com) or do you just try to simulate the vote from your account. I would think that you need to be logged in for this and therefore get the index

Comment: there may be something wrong in index.php can you please post the code?

Comment: @FrankProvost I want to simulate and Recipies.wikia.com don't requires login it just checks I.P address NO login

Comment: @Ashish Everything is correct as i can receive response using method 1 (but it just receives response not send)

Answer (score 0):

You can post the form with jQuery and catch the json response. Try something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="http://recipes.wikia.com/index.php" method="POST" onsubmit="alert(2)">
      <input type="hidden" name="title" value="User&#95;blog&#58;Kate&#46;moon&#47;Battle&#95;of&#95;the&#95;Fantasy&#95;Foods&#45;&#95;Round&#95;SIX" />
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ajax" />
      <input type="hidden" name="rs" value="axAjaxPollSubmit" />
      <input type="hidden" name="wpPollId" value="B5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB" />
      <input type="hidden" name="wpVote" value="Vote&#33;" />
      <input type="hidden" name="wpPollRadioB5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB" value="3" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
    </form>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {

            var data = $("form").serializeArray();

            $.post('http://recipes.wikia.com/index.php', data, function(jsonResponse){

                var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(jsonResponse);
                alert("The id: " + jsonObj.id);

            });
        });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its still popping Download box with `index.php` . Try it yourself

Comment: I can't, it's cross-domain, can you show the code in `http://recipes.wikia.com/index.php`

Comment: You can , Create a file 'index.html' on your computer with that code and submit it. (simple) I also don't have access to that domain (recepies.wikia.com).

Comment: You can , Create a file 'index.html' on your computer with that code and submit it. (simple) I also don't have access to that domain (recepies.wikia.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your javascript code in `$(document).ready(function(){/*your code here*/})`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*put your code here*/
    $("#contactForm").submit(function(event) 
    {
        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        /* get some values from elements on the page: */
        var $form = $( this ),
            $submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' ),
            title_value = $form.find( 'input[name="title"]' ).val(),
            action_value = $form.find( 'input[name="action"]' ).val(),
            rs_value = $form.find( 'input[name="wpPollId"]' ).val(),
            wpPollId_value = $form.find( 'input[name="title"]' ).val(),
            wpVote_value = $form.find( 'input[name="wpVote"]' ).val(),
            wpPollRadioB5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB_value = $form.find( 'input[name="wpPollRadioB5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB"]' ).val(),
            message_value = $form.find( 'textarea[name="message"]' ).val(),
            url = $form.attr('action');

        /* Send the data using post */
        var posting = $.post( url, { 
            title: title_value, 
            action: action_value, 
            rs: rs_value, 
            wpPollId: wpPollId_value,
            wpVote: wpVote_value,
            wpPollRadioB5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB: wpPollRadioB5686B741937166683ACC4DC49C515BB_value
        });

        posting.done(function( data )
        {
            /* Put the results in a div */
            $( "#contactResponse" ).html(data);

            /* Change the button text. */
            $submit.text('Sent, Thank you');

            /* Disable the button. */
            $submit.attr("disabled", true);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Its also downloading `index.php`

Comment: Sorry for late comment. I think your code is downloading index.php because you posted your form normally, not from `$.post()`. If you successfully send your form via `$.post()` try debug it with firebug.